# i am not able to assign dynamic values to the meta tag?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

Imported components in this i am using head tag of next js

```
import React, { `PureComponent` } from "react";
import Head from "next/head";

class StyleSheets extends PureComponent {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      isLoaded: false, **//State values**
      error: null,
      data: ''
    }
  }
```

**calling api in componentdidmount**
as you can see i am calling api here and storing values in state variable data

```
  componentDidMount() {
    const req_data = {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        product_id: window.location.pathname
      }),
    };

    **// i am fetching data using in componentDidMount**

    fetch(`http://15.206.113.44:8004/ecomapi/product_meta/`, req_data)
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((result) => {
        this.setState({
          isLoaded: true,
          data: result.data.name,
        });
      });



  }
```

in render part i am giving values from state to the head tag and meta tags.
but meta tags do not show any data in its content when i see the source code of the page

```
  render() {
    
    return (
      <div>
        <Head>
          <meta httpEquiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />

          **// i am using api response in following format in meta tags**
              **but meta tag doe not show values in source code of the page**

          <title>ABCD | {this.state.data}</title> 
          <meta name="title" content={this.state.data} />
          <meta name="description" content={this.state.data} />

        </Head>
        </div>
      
    );
  }
}

export default StyleSheets;
```

what is the exact problem that meta tags don't show dynamic values in its content?
how can i resolve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Two possibilities here:

1. `meta` is not a valid child of `div`
2. Typically React code is injected into a DOM element, for example:

```
ReactDOM.render(<Main />, document.getElementById('main'));
```

In the above code, my React app is being injected into a div in the body, but meta needs to be in the head.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="" content="">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="main"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here's some documentation about how to make dynamic meta:

https://create-react-app.dev/docs/title-and-meta-tags/

Essentially, React is designed to be a single-page-application framework.  One page gets one document head.  It's not great for SEO because when Google crawls your site it only sees one document.  If SEO is important to you, consider not using a SPA framework.  You can use React components on individual pages in a regular website format.

Comment: i read the document you sent. but i am not getting how to use it in my code? i am little bit confused.

Comment: Essentially you put a special string in your index.html and then on your server you use an npm package to replace the string with data each time the page is requested. This means the meta is determined server-side BUT it can be different for each time your web app is opened.

Comment: i have two questions.   1. in my project i am using next js with react js and there is no index.html file is present?     2. how to use npm package on server?   if u have any idea about it please reply. thank u.